# Touchpad 2 finger scroll speed way too fast in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, touchpad

My [ASUS Vivobook S 14](https://www.asus.com/de/laptops/for-home/vivobook/asus-vivobook-s-14-oled-k5404/) is dual booted with Ubuntu 22.04. The touchpad 2 finger scroll speed is way too fast (like 10 times the normal).

I have looked for various solutions online but none of them worked. Any fix possible ubuntu community??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change 2-finger touchpad scroll speed on Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1413750/how-to-change-2-finger-touchpad-scroll-speed-on-ubuntu-22-04)

Comment: I have the same problem. The only solution found yet is described here - https://askubuntu.com/a/1477188/1765432 But I still continue looking for a better solution, because the touchpad seems to work worse than on original OS (e.g. sensitivity).

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same problem in my asus vivobook k15 oled.2 finger scrolling is very fast. I tried the solution mentioned [here][1]; but as @llya mentioned in the comments, it work worse than the original os. One thing is that if I enable the **Windows Scrolling Personality** option in the chrome: flags, it works perfectly on chrome browser. So annoying that I can't find a way to make that systemwide.